# How much time is required for heel stretch?

Tags: kung-fu, forms, flexibility, stretching

I am not an athlete but I play football. Approximately how many days will it require to learn a heel stretch? I want to be able to raise my leg up to head level so that the sole of my foot is facing the sky. It is a part of pre-fight yoga.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with martial arts and should move to [fitness.se](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There's also not a specific time you can place to developing flexibility like this.  It depends a lot on your initial condition and specifics to your biology. The reality might be "2 days" to "Never, due to joint, bone, and tendon issues".

Comment: The answer is: a lot of days.

Comment: @Sardathrion it is a part of pre-fight yoga. Bankuei nice advice. cheers

Comment: There's a good question in here, if some things are cleared out. Very important aspects like age, body type, previous stretching experience, etc. are all determining factors. Aside from those, seeing as the tag is "kung-fu", the question is what style of kung-fu? Some styles are highly acrobatic and could do with such extensive stretching. Other styles won't do kicks higher than the knee. This stretching wouldn't be of much use then.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely dependent on your flexibility and muscle tension.  Age also plays a factor as the younger you are the easier it is to stretch muscles out.  You will have to stretch and test your flexibility to see how much progress you make before you can estimate.

No one can estimate your own personal flexibility as it differs with each person.